# IIF Function in Access query that adds three fields together and compares answer to another field

Tags: sql, iif-function

I'm using Windows Access 2010.  I'm trying to run an IIF Function, using Expression Builder, in a query on one table that asks the query to add three fields together and compare the answer to a fourth field.  If the sum of the three fields are equal to the fourth field return "Ok" if not equal return"Err".

This is the the expression I'm using:

```
SalmonRelSum: IIf([SalmonRelUM]+[SalmonRelAd]+
                  [SalmonRelUK]=SalmonReleasedCount],"Ok","Err")
```

When I run the query I get Err on all lines whether it is correct or not.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're missing `[` in `=SalmonReleasedCount]` try adding it

Comment: Thanks for catching that.  I still get Err for all data lines.  :(

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you really mean this:

```
IIf([SalmonRelUM]+[SalmonRelAd]+[SalmonRelUK]=[SalmonReleasedCount],"Ok","Err")
--------------------------------^
```

The problem is probably `NULL` values.  You can use the `NZ()` function to treat them as zeroes:

```
IIf(NZ([SalmonRelUM], 0) + NZ([SalmonRelAd], 0) + NZ([SalmonRelUK], 0) =[SalmonReleasedCount], 
    "Ok", "Err"
   )
```